# Get data from website HTMLParser Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing

I want to take three components of the website, first is Ipadress, port and protoco, I used HTMLParser in python to solve but the code below in a tag  has no attrisbute and value

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>proxy-list</title>
</head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>192.168.1.10</td>     
    <td>HTTP1</td>
    <td>Vietnam</td>
    <td>8080</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>%d1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>10.25.100.10</td>
    <td>HTTPS2</td>
    <td>Campuchia</td>
    <td>3214</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>%d2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>203.25.10.110</td>
    <td>HTTP3</td>
    <td>ThaiLan</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>%d3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>220.155.10.13</td>
    <td>HTTP4</td>
    <td>Itali</td>
    <td >1000</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>%d4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>220.155.10.113</td>
    <td>HTTP5</td>
    <td>Itali</td>
    <td >505</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>%d4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>220.155.10.115</td>
    <td>HTTPS6</td>
    <td>Itali</td>
    <td >321</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>%d4</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

So how do I get all 3 components that IPadress and port, protoco.

Comment: Anything that you've tried?

Comment: Have all the **`<tr>`** blocks the same structure? I see that the third block has no port. And don't paste code as `answers`, just edit your question.

Comment: the structure of the <tr> entirely the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get data from website using python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819057/get-data-from-website-using-python-script)

Answer (score 1):

Try using **`lxml`**:

```
from lxml import html

HTML_CODE = """<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>proxy-list</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>192.168.1.10</td>     
                <td>HTTP1</td>
                <td>Vietnam</td>
                <td>8080</td>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>%d1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10.25.100.10</td>
                <td>HTTPS2</td>
                <td>Campuchia</td>
                <td>3214</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>%d2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>203.25.10.110</td>
                <td>HTTP3</td>
                <td>ThaiLan</td>
                <td>3215</td>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>%d3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>220.155.10.13</td>
                <td>HTTP4</td>
                <td>Itali</td>
                <td >1000</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>%d4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>220.155.10.13</td>
                <td>HTTP5</td>
                <td>Itali</td>
                <td >1000</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>%d4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>220.155.10.13</td>
                <td>HTTP6</td>
                <td>Itali</td>
                <td >1000</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>%d4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>"""

tree = html.fromstring(HTML_CODE)

for block in tree.xpath('//table/tr'):
    ip, protocol, _, port, _, _ = [x.strip() for x in block.xpath('.//text()') if x.strip() not in ""]
    print "IP: {}".format(ip)
    print "Protocol: {}".format(protocol)
    print "Port: {}\n".format(port)
```

**Output:**

```
IP: 192.168.1.10
Protocol: HTTP1
Port: 8080

IP: 10.25.100.10
Protocol: HTTPS2
Port: 3214

IP: 203.25.10.110
Protocol: HTTP3
Port: 3215

IP: 220.155.10.13
Protocol: HTTP4
Port: 1000

IP: 220.155.10.13
Protocol: HTTP5
Port: 1000

IP: 220.155.10.13
Protocol: HTTP6
Port: 1000
```

Comment: but I wanted to write in HTMLParser, has be no Andrés Pérez-Albela H?

Comment: sorry Andrés Pérez-Abela H, I am very thankful for your help

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the tags yourself. I agree with Andres that `lxml` is better suited for this, but using `HTMLParser` you can create a `TableParser` class that outputs an nest array that contains a dictionary for each table row.

```
import HTMLParser
html = """<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>proxy-list</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>192.168.1.10</td>     
                <td>HTTP1</td>
                <td>Vietnam</td>
                <td>8080</td>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>%d1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10.25.100.10</td>
                <td>HTTPS2</td>
                <td>Campuchia</td>
                <td>3214</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>%d2</td>
            </tr>       
        </table>
    </body>
</html>"""

class TableParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
   def __init__(self,tags):
       self.tags=tags
       HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)
       self.in_td = False  

   def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'td':           
           self.in_td = True           
        if tag == 'tr':
            self.count = 0
            self.row = {}

   def handle_data(self, data):
       if self.in_td:           
           self.row[self.tags[self.count]] = data
           self.count = self.count +1          

   def handle_endtag(self, tag):
      self.in_td = False
      if tag == 'tr':
            self.table.append(self.row)

   def feed_tags(self,html,tags):  
       self.table=[]       
       self.feed(html)
       return self.table

tags=  ['ip','protocol','country','port','field1','field2'] 
p = TableParser(tags)    
table = p.feed_tags(html,tags)
for row in table:
    print row['ip']+','+row['protocol']+','+row['port']
```

Comment: Jaco : why? script is just get an array <tr> last was? help me?

Comment: I am not sure what you asking. I have modified my script to return an a nested array just containing the details you want.

Comment: oh no, I want get two values: 192.168.1.10,HTTP1,8080   and 10.25.100.10, HTTP2 ,   3214. help me :D

Comment: Your script prints out the same list:   [{'protocol': 'HTTPS2', 'ip': '10.25.100.10', 'port': '3214'}, {'protocol': 'HTTPS2', 'ip': '10.25.100.10', 'port': '3214'}]

Comment: help me Jaco, I have tried to edit, but I incorrigible :(

Comment: I want get all of the data of the web page, so I have to do?

Comment: I did it, but I feel is not yet stable, so you can help me see